# Regular Expression how to match any space in []

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

How to matche all space or `-` in `[]` use regular expression.

example:
`aa [ abd def ] aa` OR `aa [abd def] aa`

How to matche all space in `[]`. I want to replace space to other character like `_`.

result looks like this:
`aa [abd_def] aa` OR `aa [abd_def] aa`

I use sublime to do this. Any one can help. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar That's not the question.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a regexp replacement in a text editor.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The duplicate shows how to do it in a programming language, not an IDE.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there are ways to do this in a text editor using `\G` and `\K`.  But I don't know the exact syntax.

Comment: Actually, one of the answers shows how to do it with lookarounds.

Comment: Just saw that I made a similar comment in that question (8 years ago). I get around....